# How do I reset data on my seed file and have it start with id of 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, seed

In my app, I have a seed file that creates random Clients and Events. A client has many events while an event belongs to one client. I had to change the data so I used db:seed:replant to resent my database. However, every time I reset my database the ids also change which makes it troublesome when I try to associate clients with events and vice versa. How do I reset my data so that the Id starts at 1?

Comment: you can use `bin/rails db:reset` which drops and then recreates the database and includes your seeds.rb file. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#resetting-the-database

Comment: You can also create dynamic seed file so you dont need to depend on specific ids. if you could share the seed file, I will suggest the changes.

Comment: "when I try to associate clients with events and vice versa" - you can do that without manipulating with ids if you define and use ActiveRecord associations properly (`client.events.create(...)`). If you still insist on resetting ids: maintaining sequences for auto-incremented primary keys is the database responsibility, not the application's one. So the answer is database-dependent and you should search the answer in the DB's docs.